# How to set Financial Year dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show previous 30 year of financial year in drop down.
Eg-

```
   2019-20
   2018-19
   2017-18 and so on
```

Using javascript or jquery

Comment: Good for you, what's the question?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: This is very close to what you need. Just need to add the next year with hyphen to `value` [Generate years for drop down in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741857)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create option value dyanamically.

```js
var mySelect = $('#years');
var startYear = 2020;
var prevYear = 2019;
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  startYear = startYear - 1;
  prevYear = prevYear - 1;
  mySelect.append(
    $('<option></option>').val(startYear + "-" + prevYear).html(startYear + "-" + prevYear)
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='years'>
</select>
```

Live Demo :

https://jsfiddle.net/2ag4c3sp/2/

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var current_year = new Date().getFullYear()
 var amount_of_years = 30

  for (var i = 0; i < amount_of_years+1; i++) {
    var year = (current_year-i).toString();
    var element = '<option value="' + year + '">' + year + '</option>';
    $('select[name="financial_year"]').append(element)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='financial_year'></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:

```js
var yearsLength = 30;
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++){
  var next = currentYear+1;
  var year = currentYear + '-' + next.toString().slice(-2);
  $('#financialYear').append(new Option(year, year));
  currentYear--;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="financialYear"></select>
```